# $(this) not working inside a custom jQuery function

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I've made a jQuery countdown timer, using moment.js and [moment-duration-format plugin](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format).

Note that `$('div#countdown')` is hard-coded inside the function.  The function works as presented here. But if I change the hard-coded reference to $(this), it doesn't work.  `console.log($this)` returns an empty object.

I've tried setting $(this) to a variable at the start of the function, in case the interval was creating a scope issue, but it made no difference.

The confusing part is that I've used this exact `$.fn.xxx = function` syntax before for custom jQuery functions, and $(this) has worked fine in those functions.  Something about this particular function is tripping it up.

```
<script>
    $.fn.countdown = function ( seconds, tFormat, stopAtZero ) {
        tFormat = (typeof tFormat !== 'undefined') ? tFormat : 'hh:mm:ss';
        stopAtZero = (typeof stopAtZero !== 'undefined') ? stopAtZero : true;
        var eventTime = Date.now() + ( seconds * 1000 );
        var diffTime = eventTime - Date.now();
        var duration = moment.duration( diffTime, 'milliseconds' );
        var interval = 0;
        var counter = setInterval(function () {
            $('div#countdown').text( moment.duration( duration.asSeconds() - ++interval, 'seconds' ).format( tFormat, { trim: false }) );
            if( stopAtZero && interval >= seconds ) clearInterval( counter );
        }, 1000);
    };

    $('div#countdown').countdown( 30*60, 'mm:ss' );
</script>

<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Edit: RESOLVED. The function was fine.  It just needed to come after the Div (or after Document Load)  ::headdesk::

Comment: `this` does change meaning depending on scope; you'll have a different `this` at the window level, inside your countdown function, and inside your setInterval.  Typical workaround is to use `var self = this` to capture a reference whichever `this` you actually intend to use, and refer to `self` inside the child function.   (Although, in your case, explicitly referencing the DOM element you want, as you've done here, is probably the best solution.)

Comment: I tried that.  Set the first line of the function to: `target = $(this);` then used target inside the setInterval

Comment: Related [How does the “this” keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the function within `setTimeout()` runs under a different scope than your outer function. Hence `this` is not what you expect it to be. You need to cache the `this` reference.

Also note that you can improve the logic slightly by providing an object to the function which contains the options. Then you can use `$.extend` to provide defaults. You should also loop over `this` to enable users to provide a collection of objects to initialise the plugin on. Try this:

```js
$.fn.countdown = function(options) {
  var defaults = {
    seconds: 0,
    tFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
    stopAtZero: true,
    complete: function() {}
  };
  var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

  $(this).each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var eventTime = Date.now() + (settings.seconds * 1000);
    var diffTime = eventTime - Date.now();
    var duration = moment.duration(diffTime, 'milliseconds');
    var interval = 0;
    var counter = setInterval(function() {
      $el.text(moment.duration(duration.asSeconds() - ++interval, 'seconds').format(settings.tFormat, {
        trim: false
      }));
      if (settings.stopAtZero && interval >= settings.seconds) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        settings.complete();
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}

$('div').countdown({
  seconds: 10,
  complete: function() {
    console.log('finished!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Rory, Thanks for the suggestions. Note commentary in a near-identical answer below yours.

Comment: Can you investigate to see if there's any issues in other areas of your code. As you can see from the snippet I just edited in to my answer, it works fine. Note that you're relying on both `moment.js` and `moment-duration-format.js` - you need to ensure you include both files within your page, and in the right order

Comment: @StephenR, rorys works. Run the snippet. If your saying it doesn't you need to explain what your doing differently and why yours doesn't work. This is the correct answer.

Comment: Could it be that I'm using jQuery 3.1?

Comment: Doesn't seem so - I just updated the fiddle and that still works.

Comment: AAAARRGGH!  Figured it out.  I tried copy/pasting your exact code into my file, and it **didn't work**.  Huh.  Turns out it's because the <div> was written after the script. No $(this) because the div didn't exist yet.  Stoopid stoopid stoopid.

Marking this correct because you gave such nice suggestions for improvements (even though in this case I can't imagine ever needing to  put the exact same countdown counter on multiple elements ;-)

Comment: Ahh, that'll do it :) Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: Quick follow up... would there be a straightforward way to tell this script to call another function when the timer is up? That is, a function that could be specified in the options when calling the Countdown function.

Comment: Absolutely, you can provide a function to execute within the settings object. I updated the answer for you

Answer (score 1):

you need to capture your element at a higher scope and use it in the interval.

```
$.fn.countdown = function ( seconds, tFormat, stopAtZero ) {
    tFormat = (typeof tFormat !== 'undefined') ? tFormat : 'hh:mm:ss';
    stopAtZero = (typeof stopAtZero !== 'undefined') ? stopAtZero : true;

    //Capture this here, where it points at  $('div#countdown')
    var elem = $(this);
    //writes countdown
    console.log(elem.attr('id'));

    var eventTime = Date.now() + ( seconds * 1000 );
    var diffTime = eventTime - Date.now();
    var duration = moment.duration( diffTime, 'milliseconds' );
    var interval = 0;
    var counter = setInterval(function () {

        //this here points at window

        //writes countdown
        console.log(elem.attr('id'));

        //now use your captured element here.
        elem.text( moment.duration( duration.asSeconds() - ++interval, 'seconds' ).format( tFormat, { trim: false }) );
        if( stopAtZero && interval >= seconds ) clearInterval( counter );
    }, 1000);
};

$('div#countdown').countdown( 30*60, 'mm:ss' );
```

Comment: I've tried that. It makes no difference. (Note the third paragraph of the question)

Comment: even trying to capture elem as you suggest, `console.log(elem)` returns `Object [  ]`

Comment: Yes, elem is an object? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: console.log(elem.id) returns undefined

Comment: But a minute ago you said it returned `Object`. Where exactly are you putting this logging?

Comment: first two lines of the function. Set a variable to $(this), then console.log the variable.

console.log(elem) returned object[ ]. console.log(elem.id) returned undefined

Comment: My fault, should be `console.log(elem.attr('id'))`. My jquery is rusty

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example (I removed the not-relevant-to-the-question `moment()` and formatting code; otherwise this is the same except for capturing "this" at the proper scope.)

```js
$.fn.countdown = function ( seconds, tFormat, stopAtZero ) {
        tFormat = (typeof tFormat !== 'undefined') ? tFormat : 'hh:mm:ss';
        stopAtZero = (typeof stopAtZero !== 'undefined') ? stopAtZero : true;
        var eventTime = Date.now() + ( seconds * 1000 );
        var diffTime = eventTime - Date.now();
        var duration = 5000;
        var interval = 0;
        var self = this; // <-- capture the DOM element here
        var counter = setInterval(function () {
            // and use it here:
            $(self).text((5000 - ++interval) + ' seconds');
            if( stopAtZero && interval >= seconds ) clearInterval( counter );
        }, 1000);
    };

    $('div#countdown').countdown( 30*60, 'mm:ss' );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```